# How to share many documents at once in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, sharing

I want to share an entire collection or many docs at once instead of manually adding a user at a time for every document now that my manager switched to a new Google account. Can it be done? If yes, how?

Comment: I was able to easily share an entire collection. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I missed that you must right-click and when realizing that I could share the collection. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share many documents at once, select the documents in your Google Docs list, press the 'Share' button (or right-click and select 'Share') and add the people you want  to share with.

Comment: You can also select the folder /collection and share all the documents.

Comment: Thanks. It works for documents that I own. I could right-click and select share.